# Understanding "bazer muy bien aparejadas y ennervadas"

Tags: traducción

I'm trying to understand a fifteenth century text, and I've come across the following:

> ... las quales dichas syete ystorias nos obligamos de bazer muy bien aparejadas y ennervadas por de dentro e por de fuera e pintadas al olio sobre muy buen aparejo

I don't understand the phrase 'de bazer muy bien aparejadas y ennervadas' though.

Does anybody know what the modern Spanish equivalent might be / can explain the meaning, either in Spanish or English?

Answer (score 11):

After some searching in old Google books, I came to the conclusion that *bazer* is in fact a typical OCR error when scanning *hazer*, which is an old form of *hacer*: *to do/to make*. See for instance the following screenshot of a Google book where I searched for *bazer* and all instances of *hazer* are highlighted:

[image: gb]

For the rest of the sentence it would be better if you could show us some more of the text before this passage, but it seems that seven paintings were very well painted over a very good support.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of *bazer* was correctly explained by @rsanchez: it is, in fact, *hazer*.

*Aparejadas* refers to the *aparejos* in a building (*brickwork*) or a ship (*riggings*). And *ennervadas* refers to the *nervaduras* (*ribs*) in a building. This is: the framework on which the building is based.

Putting all together, when the writer promises to *hazer muy bien aparejadas y ennervadas* his stories, he means that he will build them on a good foundation.

Answer (score 0):

*Bazer*? Are you sure it's not *Fazer*?
*Fazer* = modern *Hacer*.

So: *bazer muy bien aparejadas y ennervadas* = *hacer muy bien aparejadas y ennervadas.*

*Aparejadas*: linked to.

*Ennervadas*: united (although I'm not 100% sure about this meaning, I didn't find a proper definition for *ennervadas*, even in Spanish).

Comment: In this case, *ennervadas* means buttressed with *nervaduras* (ribs).

Answer (score 0):

I want to add:

1. Enervar: Debilitar, quitar las fuerzas. (Weaken, take strenght) [Google translate sorry if wrong]. From the latin enervare (weaken)

so the phrase 'de hazer muy bien aparejadas y ennervadas' would be translated as 'to make them [the stories] liked and weaken', if you add more text maybe we'll answer clearer.

Comment: Not in this case. *Ennervadas* refers to the opposite: well buttressed with *nervaduras* (ribs).